# Configuring CodeIgniter to run locally with Apache on Mac OS X

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, localhost

I've got a CodeIgniter project that until now has been only run remotely (it was built on a server... not my idea!). I pulled it from GitHub to my local machine (running OS X 10.6 where I have MySQL and PHP installed and configured).

When I go to the home page (http://localhost) it works fine (connects to DB, runs all the PHP, presents me with the correct page)... but when I click any links (for example, a link on a product that goes to http://localhost/product/details/464) I get a blank page or "Not Found The requested URL /product/details/464 was not found on this server." instantly.

It's as if somewhere in my stack Apache or PHP or CodeIgniter is dropping the ball and not realizing it's supposed to be interpreting this URL and directing it to the proper controller, etc instead is trying to serve it up as if it's a static file. I might be missing something obvious here, but I've been trying to troubleshoot for a few hours with no luck. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I've never actually fooled with CodeIgniter so I won't answer.  But, does the framework use any `.htaccess` files to redirect to the front controller?  If so, were they in your github repo when you pulled it down to your local machine?

Comment: http://localhost/index.php/product/details/464 does this work ?

Comment: The .htaccess file is in the git repo, are there other global .htaccess files that might be messing it up? I am going to attempt using MAMP as GregSchoen suggested below and then report back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .htaccess is your problem, it's not properly redirecting.

The default installation of Apache/PHP in Mac is bizarre. I had problems with CodeIgniter and Apache not recognizing the .htaccess file. Using MAMP [http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html] is a lot more stable and comparable to a Hosted environment.

Comment: Thanks for that MAMP tip Greg! I wasted lots of time getting MySQL set up on my Mac for no reason, but now luckily everything is working properly with MAMP!

Answer (score 3):

Did you set the base_url and the index_page in the config.php file? If your Apache is not running mod_rewrite, you need to either enable mod_write and make sure you have your .htaccess file, or else set your index_page to "index.php" so that CodeIgniter works without mod_rewrite.

```
$config['base_url']     = 'http://yourlocalurl/';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

Answer (score 3):

Mac set up:

```
$config['base_url']     = 'http://localhost:8000';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

Terminal: `php -S localhost:8000`

If that doesn't work, make sure apache is running...
Terminal: `sudo apachectl start`
Then run again: `php -S localhost:8000`